# How to run a correlation test between two dataframes with the same # of columns but different rows?

Tags: r, correlation

So I'm using the xCell package to compare two groups - HPV+ Head and Neck Cancer Cases, and HPV+ Cervix Cancer Cases. However, when I try to run the code:

```
Cesc = xCell_analysis_CESC_POS_FINAL[rownames(scores),colnames(xCell_analysis_CESC_POS_FINAL)]
Cor = corr.test(cesc_test, hnsc_pos_test,adjust='none')
qplot(x=rownames(Cor$r),y=diag(Cor$r),
      fill=diag(Cor$p)<0.05,geom='col',
      main='HPV+ HNSC vs HPV+ CESC',
      ylab='Pearson R', xlab= "") + labs(fill = "p-value<0.05") +
  theme_classic() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 45, hjust = 1))
```

I get an error telling me:

```
Error in cor(x, y, use = use, method = method) : incompatible dimensions
```

So basically I figured out that the problem is in the second line of code:

```
Cor = corr.test(cesc_test, hnsc_pos_test,adjust='none')
```

as the dataframes "cesc_test" and "hnsc_pos_test" both have the same number of columns (18) but a different number of rows (139 vs 70). Am I using the right correlation test for these two dataframes? And what am I doing wrong?

Comment: To calculate the correlation of two variables/vectors you need to ensure that the values in both variables are pairs that belong to the same case/patient. Since your dataframes have different row counts there seems to be a mismatch between the two dataframes regarding the cases they contain. You could join the datasets first using an ID column and then apply the correlation test. You can do the join with `dplyr::inner_join()` for example.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to review your null hypothesis.

Like @Till said in comment, correlation test only applies to cases where you have 2 values that belong to the same subject. Putting into context, it means that you should only do correlation test if the same patient developed both head & neck and cervical cancers.

You can also do correlation test between different variables within the same cancer dataset.

But since you want to compare the value of interest between two datasets, maybe you want to compare the mean / median between the two types of cancers instead? In which case, a `t.test` or `wilcox.test` may be more appropriate.